# scrapy - unable to properly extract multiple URLs from <p> tags into items list

Tags: python, xpath, dictionary, css-selectors, scrapy

I'm pretty much newbie to Scrapy and Python, so kindly bear with me if this question sounds silly. The contents I am trying to scrape is all within one or more paragraph tags on the website. I'm having difficulty extracting the fields (URLs) if they are in more than one paragraph tags. If it were only one link per paragraph tag per block, or in table cells, I could easily get them. But in this case, even after spending more than a day, I am not able to extract those multiple links from multiple paragraph tags.

The contents I'm trying to extract has the following HTML-source structure:

```
<p class="date">June 30, 2014 </p>
<h2> SOME TITLE 1 </h2>
<p> SOME TEXT 1 <a href="http://www.link1.com">LINK 1</a> and the <a href="http://www.link2.com">LINK 2</a>.</p>

<p class="date">June 27, 2014</p>
<h2>SOME TITLE 2</h2>
<p>SOME TEXT 2-A </p>
<p>SOME TEXT 2-B <a href="meetings.php">here</a>. SOME TEXT </p>
<p>SOME TEXT 2-C <a href="website.php">WCI, Inc. website</a>, SOME TEXT. </p>

<p class="date">June 27, 2014 </p>
<h2>SOME TITLE 3 </h2>
<p>SOME TEXT 3 <a href="http://www.anotherlink.com">SOME TEXT</a>.</p>

<p><a href="news-archive.php" class="button buttonLtGray floatR">Previous Entries</a></p>
```

Kindly help.My code is given below:

```
class Wcispider(Spider):

name = "wci"
allowed_domains = "www.wci-inc.org/"
start_urls = ["http://www.wci-inc.org/index.php"]

def parse(self, response):

    items = []
    sel = Selector(response)

    date = sel.css(".date::text")

    i = 0

    for eacDate in date:
        item = WciItem()

        item['date'] = eacDate.extract()

        item['title'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="news"]/h2').extract()[i]
        item['url'] = sel.css(".date ~ p a").extract()[i]

        print item['date']
        print item['title']
        print item['url']
        i += 1
        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you can have more than one link in each "news post body", your one-at-a-time iteration won't work.

I would try to group them together under the "date of the news post" node, and then loop for a while. (It's unfortunate that your target document doesn't containerize the news posts :)

The cool thing about the Scrapy Selector is that you can call `xpath` on the results of an `xpath` call. Check it:

```
#get all interesting date paragraphs
date = sel.xpath('//*/p[@class="date"]')

for eacDate in date:
    #eacDate is a paragraph node
    #extract all of the paragraphs after this one at the same level in the DOM,
    #then loop until you find a date paragraph, since that marks the start of the next section
    urls = []
    next_paragraphs = eacDate.xpath("following-sibling::p")
    for p in next_paragraphs:
        if p.xpath("@class").extract() == [u'date']:
            break
        urls.extend(p.xpath("a/@href").extract())
    print urls
```

You might want to read up on XPath Axes: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 0):

> ## FORWARD NOTE:  POSITIVE LOOK AHEAD; (?=X)
>
> x = from the very beginning of a single/multiple string you reattempting to match!
>
> > ```
> >   (?=http:)\w+.\/\/.{3}.\w+.{4}
> > ```

[image: CAPTURE ALLLLLLL MATCH THE EXPRESSION]

Because there hasn't been much action on this thread I'm going to Simply just post quick little note about using RegEx... there has been 364 views and just one answer and for $YOU ... stumbling upon this by chance because you googled how to ... regex, its not all [$unknown_langue] is not as foreign as the brain makes out to be (been there!) think of regular expression I want you to think of it this way...

> ## FAIR WARNING
>
> > About to try to explain in a universal context of how I first started >>to view regex, no need for the flames, this is for those starting out >> and could use any humanized way of explaining... not just from a >>video or forums reply linking to other replies (or worse  feeding >>people answers)

1. Picture the entire section of where your data is like is written on a peice of paper... you want some thing out of it? USE SCISSORS.
2. Where its just one line, multiple lines... remove a peice, you can visualy see where you want to cut right?? There must be a LOGIC|PATTERN in what you are trying to get (in the case of data mining, yeah almost always)
3. Stepping back to reality for a sec(oops... GRAVITY!!!!) obviously you gota learn the rules but same principle, you pick where you want to start, end, exlude ... substitute! in the posted question... we wanted a ALL data that followd a PATTERN that we live with ... EVERY DAY... *http://etc.etc.etc*

SO... a pattern .... then we determined we wanted ALL of this patter in this text.

AGAIN! in the case of the posted question one could simply say...

> ## START every WITH the capture|matching...
>
> or cutting of if your still on that lol

All my data data I want start with http ...
  AND WE ALL KNOW that the end is going to (in this case atleast lol) be .com... is there a there .org also? In my regex posted above you see that all I SAID was....  start WITH http:
    (?=http:)
(?=etc) = this is called a positive look ahead! (many way to go about this....)

> > so far selected (any in data)
> >     http:
>
> .w+=//
>
> so far selected ... why? look it up!! there some charaters dat ARE USE >by regex so if they are in you data upi gat use \before writing them... >it called an escape!
>
> > http://

now for sure its goin to be 3 charachters... WWW + a coma right? so I said select next three

> http://www

the need to be ANYTHIN up until we know that it wil en in a other coma (MAYBE theres number!! \w... the w stands for WORD! )

> http://www.thiscouldgoonforininfinitybutnotuntilIreachAcomaisaystoprigh
>   there.

Theres flipside to it all! .co .io... that just 2 .com .org is... well i know you can count....   THE POINT?!
1.DEFINE YOUR NEED!
2.IDENTIFY THE PATTERN
3.REGEX is a simple and also mind-numbingly complex so...start from the basics and realy understand it (not difficult, its like learning periodic table in high school, or w.e lol point is if you can deal with python, you for sure should be able to get regx)